# How to apply Metronic 5 to Angular-cli and Nodejs project?

Tags: node.js, angular-cli, metronic

Recently I bought the Metronic Theme ([Metronic homepage](https://themeforest.net/item/metronic-responsive-admin-dashboard-template/4021469)) and I want to apply it to my ongoing MEAN Project (Mongoose, Express, Angular-cli, Nodejs).

I do realize that the Mongoose and Express part of the project is no affected by the Theme, but how do I install it? The documentation is kinda unfriendly (to me).

Any help would be welcome, since this is my first time applying a CSS theme to a project.

Comment: It's self-described as well documented and comes with support - that's not provided by SO, you need to talk to the distributors.

Comment: Its said in their support page that Item support doesn't include "Installation services"  as shown here: [Support page](https://themeforest.net/item/metronic-responsive-admin-dashboard-template/4021469/support)

Comment: Well that's unfortunate, but still not a question for SO. You need a specific question with a [mcve].